# What is the refference for the hadeeth about scholars being the heirs of the prophets?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

So far I have found 2 daef hadeeth
https://sunnah.com/search?q=The+scholars+are+the+heirs+of+the+Prophets

Is there a hadeeth that mentions it with a stronger chain?

Comment: Different scholars may come to different qualifications.

Comment: SubhanAllah, JazakAllahu khairan

Answer (score 1):

Sunan Abi Dawud 3641

classed sahih by Albani

https://sunnah.com/abudawud/26

Answer (score 1):

The hadith statement appears in several ahadith:

> Kathir ibn Qays said: I was sitting with AbudDarda' in the mosque of Damascus.
>
> A man came to him and said: AbudDarda, I have come to you from the town of the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) for a tradition that I have heard you relate from the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ). I have come for no other purpose.
> He said: I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: If anyone travels on a road in search of knowledge, Allah will cause him to travel on one of the roads of Paradise. The angels will lower their wings in their great pleasure with one who seeks knowledge, the inhabitants of the heavens and the Earth and the fish in the deep waters will ask forgiveness for the learned man. The superiority of the learned man over the devout is like that of the moon, on the night when it is full, over the rest of the stars. **The learned are the heirs of the Prophets, and the Prophets leave neither dinar nor dirham, leaving only knowledge,** and he who takes it takes an abundant portion.
> ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3641), [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/introduction/223) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2682) it was also reported by imam Ahmad and ad-Darimi in their al-Musnad)

While Hafiz Zubair 'Ali Za'i qualified it as *da'if* in the "Darussalam" editions, al-Albani qualified it as *sahih* (Sunan abi Dawod) or maybe more exactly *hassan* as the qualification -made by ibn Hajar- in [Mishkaat al-Massabih](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:212) says. However these ahadith are not free from discussions, imam at-Tirmidhi in his version already points at a disconnection in the narrator chain and points out that al-Bukhari considered this version as stronger, while the versions of ibn Majah and abu Dawood wouldn't have this disconnection. And this is not the only issue here.

However there's a sahih narration that somewhat may support it:

> 'Aisha said, "When Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) died, his wives intended to send 'Uthman to Abu Bakr asking him for their share of the inheritance." Then 'Aisha said to them, "Didn't Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) say, 'Our (Apostles') property is not to be inherited, and whatever we leave is to be spent in charity?'"
> ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6730), [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1758) and [al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/518200))

Further Allah the Almghity says:

> And **We had certainly given to David and Solomon knowledge**, and they said, "Praise [is due] to Allah , who has favored us over many of His believing servants." (15)
> **And Solomon inherited David**. He said, "O people, we have been taught the language of birds, and we have been given from all things. Indeed, this is evident bounty." (16) ([27:15-16](https://legacy.quran.com/27/15-16))

Here Solomon or Sulayman () only inherited prophethood and knowledge by consensus of all scholars.